# How do I change the file path when writing a VBA (Excel) application that writes from an Excel file into a txt file?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the file path when writing a VBA (Excel) application that writes from an Excel file into a text file? Whatever I do, it either just gives me an error or creates it in the same folder (Documents).

Full relevant code:

```
Dim x As Integer

Dim tmp As String


Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim File As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    File = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Viteria_mancante_o_in_esaurimento.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Append As #1
    cellValue = Range("C2").Value
    Write #1, cellValue
    cellValue = Range("D2").Value
    Write #1, cellValue
    Close #1
tmp = "C" + CStr(12 + x) + ":" + "D" + CStr(12 + x)
Worksheets("Foglio2").Range(tmp).Value2 = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("C2:D2").Value2
x = x + 1
End Sub
```

EDIT:

[Added image of cells turning red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJDC6.png)

Comment: Note: the code I am using is: File = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Filename.txt"

Comment: It’s better if you post all the relevant code

Comment: Done that, see my answer

Comment: You can edit your question and paste the code inside. Please delete the answer as others may get confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
File = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Filename.txt"
```

With the full path where you want the file location. For example:

```
File = "C:\MyFolder\Filename.txt"
```

And correct this line:

```
Open myFile For Append As #1
```

To this:

```
Open File For Append As #1
```

I also suggest that you add option explicit at the beginning of the vba module so you prevent from having undeclared variables

Comment: "Run time error 75: error in accessing path/file".  

I checked and the path is correct, is it because i'm on a network?

Comment: I corrected the runtime error, but now I have another problem whose source I can't trace: after a few clicks, some of the cells the text is written in (in the excel file) suddenly gain a red tinge. Any clues?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the cells?

Comment: That seems to be a conditional format. Please check

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm inexperienced in VB and VBA. What do you mean with conditional format?

Comment: Not a vba issue, but check if cells have regular conditional format. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this actually works in my favor, so I'm going to pretend that "it's not a bug, it's a feature" :)